# How to keep certain attribute table features selected while I clear my query builder? (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, query

Is this possible? I want to see all my points, and also select a few to stand out from the rest.

This is for a school project. The instructions state to use query builder, go into a layer to select the attributes, then go back to clear the query builder (expecting the points to still stay selected).

Comment: Please indicate what software you're using, either in the question or by adding a tag.

Comment: What you might want to do is run your query, then copy and paste them as a new temporary scratch layer -that way your initial selection remains... would that work?